# How to limit UILabel text using objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I have created `Tableview cell`  with custom `UILabel`. For this `UILabel` data, I am loading from `NSMutableArray`. `NSMutableArray` data loading from `JSON`. Now the problem is I need to limit the tableview cell `UILabel` text. Here below one example

Now :

```
-------------------------
12.132454556
-------------------------
```

Needed :

```
-------------------------
12.13
-------------------------
```

My Code :

```
pointbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arraydata objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

Above tableview cell label data I need to `show 5 digits` only including `"."`.  Some times NSMutableArray value will come `"null"`, So based on that also I need to make some solution.

I have tried by using below code but, If my value `"null"` then its throwing exceptions.

```
temp = [[arraydata objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]stringValue];

        if ([temp length] > 5) {
            NSRange range = [temp rangeOfComposedCharacterSequencesForRange:(NSRange){0, 5}];
            temp = [temp substringWithRange:range];
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to convert to float:

```
    if ([arraydata objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] != nil) {
        pointbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f%%",[[arraydata objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]floatValue]];
    }
    else {
        pointbl.text = @"0";
    }
```

Comment: I need to add % after foat avlue like "2.11%"...how to do?@anhtu

Comment: If I received null values what will happen
?

Comment: Edited my answer. If received null , what do you want for it? display "0%" or anything?

Comment: If value Null into NSMutableArray..I want to show "-" symbol!

Comment: Can you editi ur code. I am using multiple text label like above I dont want to use If statement, just want to simply solve this one. If value null into array I want to show "-" symbol "0" mean It will show 0! please help me!

Comment: Please help me @anhtu I need to show after float % and if value empty I want to show "-" symbol...Please...If I have already used lots of time...Its bad for good code if we taking more

Comment: Above code final brackets making error.plz recheck it again

Comment: Now Its showing @"%.2f\%" Incompatable formate warnings!

Comment: Try [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f%%",[[arraydata objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]floatValue]]

Comment: Edited, one more time. :)

Comment: Thank you @anhtu and Horst..Great help for me!Thx lot!

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution would be to add `temp != nil` to the if statement.

However, you may implement this in a different way. What's the type of the objects that are saved in `arraydata`? If's it a float value (and not a string, as can be concluded from your code samples), you can simply use `NSNumberFormatter` for the display. Even simpler, you can use: `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"0.2f", floatValue]` and it will give you at least most of what you're looking to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

// as you are loading values from json so, it can have "null" value ("null" in string format, different from nil if object is empty)

```
float a = [yourValue floatValue];
label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",a];
```